# Is Island Gigantism Necessary to have Megafauna even if I have Solved the Other Problems of Energy, Weight and Heat?

Tags: environment, fauna

I want to have megafauna on my world. I have already solved the structural problems related to megafauna by having strong but light bones, and the animals breathe a "magic" air that provides the necessary energy.

My question revolves around the effect of island gigantism, where in a closed ecosystem (an island) the animals favor growing to a large size due to minimal predation and competition (only having to worry about other species).

So, **do I need the effect of Island Gigantism to have megafauna on my world, or is it not necessary if I have already solved the core problems of energy, weight and heat?**

Comment: ??? We have [megafauna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Megafauna) in our real world, and Earth had even larger megafauna in the past, and no, most megafauna does not (and did not) live on small islands.

Comment: VTC: You want to ask if a Real World observation is necessary after using magic to resolve what the Real World won't allow you to do? (a) You're not asking a specific question relating to a rule of your world, so VTC for not asking a Q according to the [help]. (b) Why are you even asking this question? If you want Foster's Rule to be necessary in your world, make that decision. If you don't, choose not to. Is it necessary? No, obviously not, not for an imaginary world of your own creation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### No you don't want islands

the largest terrestrial animals evolve on continents not islands. Island gigantism is about small animals becoming larger, *but* bigger animals usually evolve to be smaller on islands, because resources are limited. This is called [insular dwarfism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insular_dwarfism#:%7E:text=Insular%20dwarfism%2C%20a%20form%20of,of%20dwarf%20breeds%2C%20called%20dwarfing.).

Answer (score 6):

**Nope**

There are loads of real big animals that did not evolve on islands.

**Indricotherium**

[image]

**Irish Elk**

[image]

**Jumbo Fish Gobbler**

[image]

**Migratory Coat Hook**

[image]

**This guy whose name I forget. He was in that movie with Jeff Goldblum.**

[image]

Comment: Downvote because your Indricotherium is so close to the edge of the frame that it has bent its nose down.  "Hep be!" it said.  "Daron!  By doze!".  But no.  You just stood there, neck craned back, giggling.

Comment: Downvoted because you said they did not evolve on islands but Ireland is an island.

Comment: /Ireland is an island/ accounting for its nickname in the US, "Iceland".

Comment: @Willk I don't understand that one I'm afraid.

Comment: "Iceland" sounds like Island if you pronounce the s, as one should.  And Americans are notorious for poor geographical knowledge.  Small Atlantic island countries?    Maybe I was trying too hard.

Comment: @Daron: *Megaloceros giganteus* lived all over Europe and western Asia, from Ireland to Lake Baikal.

Comment: @Willk I think it's a bit of a stretch. Especially when Ireland is often pronounced eye-ear-land in the states.

Answer (score 2):

More magical plants/more energy dense plants on the island

You have some options

A. If you are fine with the fauna just being gigantic overall, then it could be while most of the island's fauna is still small by megafauna standards, it's still gigantic by ours(if that's applicable)

B. The magic plants are more energy dense on the island, so the islands "baseline" size for the fauna is significantly larger, and so animals on the island would evolve to be gigantic, as small animals get larger, and larger animals get smaller, but if the baseline is, energy wise, that the island has more resources so the baseline is much larger with little in the way for natural predators of the herbivores, and scarce competition for the carnivores,
you'd probably get gigantic herbivores and specialized carnivores, which isn't as size dependent, but overall every would evolve to be far larger. So NO you've already solved the problem with magical energy power creatures, there just needs to be far more on the island for the creatures to end up larger.

Answer (score 1):

I just came across your question, and something popped into my mind. Call it crazy, but you *could* go the Godzilla route.

There exists a natural uranium reactor in Gabon, Africa. It's formed by the perfect setup of Uranium that's been enriched via another natural process. The result is an atomic chain reaction that has existed and been running for quite a long time if I remember correctly. Since it has no "controls" whatsoever, I'm sure that all sorts of particles are being emitted - not to mention that when you split uranium atoms, you build up Plutonium (there's more to this, like the uranium having to be bombarded with neutrons).

Getting to the point, Godzilla was a regular island lizard just minding his business when he was exposed to radiation supposedly. And there it is. You could explain gigantism via radiation exposure.

I know, crazy, but I figured I'd mention it!

Comment: Much honorable precedent for the Godzilla route.  Plus if Mechagodzilla comes from space your world will benefit from the presence of some natural Godzillae.

Comment: Kaiju is both the singular and plural form for what Godzilla and other gigantic type figures. See John Scalzi's Kaiju Preservation Society.

Comment: I am not confident all kaiju share the creation mechanism you invoke here.  Certainly they are not all equally useful!   I wanted to be specific to those in Order Godzillaformes.

Comment: I think that once a kaiju exists, it's a species, and as a species, it can therefore reproduce. You might say "well what are the chances its reproductive system was intact," or "what are the chances of a female kaiju and male kaiju being created within a reasonable enough amount of time where they'd have a chance to meet and mate?" I would counter with "if you're suspending enough belief to the point where you expect the radiation to not kill the original creature outright, but to instead create the kaiju, offspring isn't a far leap at that point. I'd also posit that kaiju are hermaphroditic.